# Dart List Model class cannot be show

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code parse from data with my model **Note** and **Book**

```dart
final data = rows.map((result) {
  return NoteWithBook(
    note: result.readTable(notes),
    book: result.readTable(books),
  );
 }).toList();
print(data); // ouput [NoteWithBook]
```

model class:

```dart
class NoteWithBook extends Equatable {
  final Note note;
  final Book book;

  NoteWithBook({
    @required this.note,
    @required this.book,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [note, book];
}
```

from the code result/ouput:

```dart
[NoteWithBook]
```

And my expect ouput is:

```dart
[
NoteWithBook(
Note(id:...),
Book(id:...)
),

NoteWithBook(
Note(id:...),
Book(id:...)
),

NoteWithBook(
Note(id:...),
Book(id:...)
),
]
```

Comment: What is going on with your Lorem Ipsum???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override the toString() method using the Equatable library, You will have to set **stringify** flag is true.
By default, a stringify flag is false, and that's why toString will return just instance of the return type.

So your NoteWithBook class should be like this:

```
class NoteWithBook extends Equatable {
  final Note note;
  final Book book;

  NoteWithBook({
    @required this.note,
    @required this.book,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [note, book];

  @override
  bool get stringify => true;
}
```